# How to update WCF service reference dynamically in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

How to update WCF service reference dynamically in silverlight ?

Suppose I have created WCF service in my system and added reference to silverlight project, now when I host this on server I want that automatically it takes that system reference .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Tim's post:

[Managing service references and endpoint configurations for Silverlight applications](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/04/05/managing-service-references-in-silverlight-applications-for-different-environments.aspx)